# Exclude column values in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

i've been searching for a solution to this for a while now. Though i'm getting a rather obscure 'Type mismatch' error and im not really sure where it comes from.

So my goal is to create a generic function, that takes two columns from different sheets and verifies whether the values in one column do not show in the second column.

```
Public Function ExcludeColumns(needle_sheet As Worksheet, needle_column As Integer, haystack_sheet As Worksheet, haystack_column As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant

    ' Loop column in needle sheet
    For Each rw In needle_sheet.Rows
        If needle_sheet.Cells(rw.Row, needle_column).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

var = Application.Match(Cells(rw.Row, needle_column).Value, Worksheets(haystack_sheet).Columns(haystack_column), 0)

        If Not IsError(var) Then
            MsgBox ("Value found")
        Else:
            MsgBox ("Value not found")
        End If
    Next rw
End Function
```

Comment: on what row do you get the type mismatch error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line with the `Application.Match` contains two errors:

- for the first parameter, you have to give the information where the cells come from. Add the `needle_sheet` before `Cells`, else Excel will take it from the `activesheet`
- For the second paramater, `haystack_sheet` is already a worksheet.

Additionally, you have to limit your loop (for example to `UsedRange`), else it will loop till the very end of the sheet.

Try this:

```
Public Function ExcludeColumns(needle_sheet As Worksheet, needle_column As Integer, haystack_sheet As Worksheet, haystack_column As Integer) As Boolean
Dim var As Variant, rw as Range

' Loop column in needle sheet
For Each rw In needle_sheet.UsedRange.Rows
    DoEvents

    If needle_sheet.Cells(rw.Row, needle_column).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

    var = Application.Match(needle_sheet.Cells(rw.Row, needle_column).Value, haystack_sheet.Columns(haystack_column), 0)

    If Not IsError(var) Then
        MsgBox ("Value found")
    Else:
        MsgBox ("Value not found")
    End If
Next rw
End Function
```

Comment: Oh well, guess i've been staring to the same code for way too long... Thank you very muchè